# more button need to show after some count

Tags: php, yii

```
if(count($fetchExperiences) > 0)
    {

        $i=0;
        foreach($fetchExperiences as $fetchExperience)
        {
           $sqlExperiencedat  = $db->createCommand(" code ");
        $fetchExperiencesdat  = $sqlExperiencedat->queryAll();
        $tdyyy=date('YYYY-mm-dd');
            if(strtotime($tdyyy)<strtotime($fetchExperience['experience_date']))
            {
        foreach($fetchExperiencesdat as $fetchExperiencesdatt)
         {
        if(strtotime($tdyyy)<strtotime($fetchExperiencesdatt['avail_date']))
        {

            //echo $fetchExperiencesdatt['avail_date'];
            $tth=1;
        }
         }
            if($tth==1){
              //fetchExperiencesdatt code
             }
         }
       }
       if(count($fetchCountExperiences) > 8){ 
       <a class="more_experience" style="clear:both;"><span onclick="getMoreExperiences1('<?            php echo count($userResults);?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>','8')">More Experiences</span></a>
       }

    }
}
```

My question is that I want more button after `$fetchexperiences` count is greater than 8. It is fine. But in between `$fetchexperiences` loop there is a loop for `$fetchExperiencesdat`. by the loop if there is no experince with in availdate it is not shown. so the probelm is more button is display not after 8 because of some `$fetchExperiencesdat` elements should be hidden. So please give me any solution for this.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand where your count experiences are coming from. However, the problem your code has is that fetchCountExperiences is not given a value.

```
   if(count($fetchCountExperiences) > 8){ 
   <a class="more_experience" style="clear:both;"><span onclick="getMoreExperiences1('<?            php echo count($userResults);?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>','8')">More Experiences</span></a>
   }
```

Looks like it should be

```
   if(count($fetchExperiences) > 8){ 
   <a class="more_experience" style="clear:both;"><span onclick="getMoreExperiences1('<?            php echo count($userResults);?>','<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>','8')">More Experiences</span></a>
   }
```